# SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 only on solution rebuild

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, authorization, roles

I have a site built using MVC4 which is getting content out of a database and it all works fine.

If I then rebuild the solution and try to refresh the page to check my changes, I will always get the SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 saying that I cannot connect to the server.

However, if I then browse to my homepage and then back to the page I was looking at it will work fine.

Does anyone know what could cause this problem as it is really annoying

**EDIT**

Further to this I have found it is when the AuthorizationContext filterContext is being loaded after the rebuild that it cannot connect to the db

**EDIT 2**

As with neil below I have found that I only get the problem if I try to access a page that has had a role assigned to it

Comment: Is your context initialized in the Home page somehow and stored in a Session ?

Comment: No, the Context is initialised in each controller that uses it

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the exact same problem and can trace it to the .ASPXAUTH session cookie in the browser.  Delete that cookie and the database error goes away until the next rebuild.

The error occurs regularly if you are authenticated and then rebuild the project and try to browse any page that either:

- Requires authentication
- Makes a call to the User object (e.g. `@if (User.IsInRole("Administrators"))`)

If you have the AuthorizeAttribute filter set in App_Start/FilterConfig.cs you'll get this on every page.

This seems to be new behavior following the most recent Patch Tuesday updates.  Previously, I was seeing weird behavior where I would remain logged in but I would loose my roll membership.  After the most recent patches, it seems Simple Membership chokes when it gets a bad .ASPXAUTH cookie (invalid because of the rebuild).

I've got the correct connection string in InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs but it's like Simple Membership is defaulting to something else in this one instance.

Note that I've moved the Simple Membership databases from the original (localDb) to a full-fledged (local) SQL Server instance.  Don't know why that would matter, and it works fine in all other cases.

**Update:**

I've also tried making the connection string name the same as the EF context name (e.g. "ProjectContext") on the theory that it is defaulting to the standard convention, but that made no difference.  I am explicitly identifying the connection string name in all my context class constructors (using the `: base("connectionString")` syntax) and Simple Membership is able to find the right connection string all other times.

**Update 2:**

The problem only occurs after rebuild when accessing a page protected *by role*. A simple `[Authorize]` won't trigger it.  You need something like `[Authorize(Role="Admin")]`.  I've replicated this on a new MVC 4 project with no other modifications, using the default (localDb) database. Clear the cookie and that same user can access the protected content w/o any problems. I believe this is a core .NET or MVC bug and needs to be reported as such.

Comment: I also found this as a problem only when applying roles, forgot to mention it though

Comment: I posted this as a bug at http://forums.asp.net/t/1861804.aspx/1?SQL+Network+Interfaces+error+26+on+solution+rebuild.  We'll see if it gets any attention...

Comment: @NeilLaslett any updates? I have this same issue and can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm still having this exact issue, did you guys ever solve yours?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me while rebuilding the application when I was logged in the browser.

Deleting cookies fixed the problem for me.

Comment: God, you're my hero! I've lost whole day for fixing this issue, and finally I've found your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using SimpleMembership, this bug occurs with any use of Roles-not just in the controller, but also when I use:

if(Roles.IsUserInRole(rolename){...

I am late to the game with this answer, but I added  [InitializeSimpleMembership] to my home controller and I think that fixed it.